# This should be really simple, had winter break after intro to programming but hitting issues

Tags: java, intellij-idea

OK, so, winter break... yeah
Well long story short, we upgraded from bluej to intellij! :D
I have decided to play around with it and make some simple stuff but I cant even get the MOST basic of stuff to work and I have no idea why.....

```
    //return a int
    public class Testing 
{
        public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
            //field
            public int sum = 0;

            //method to change field
            public int method(int z)
            {
                this.sum = z;
                return this.sum;
            }
     }
}
```

Explaining the obvious, I understand this. is not needed but I have a habbit of that and I see it as a good habit as it prevents certain minor mistakes. also i know the field of num should be private BUT intelliJ doesn't like that.
java: illegal start of expression is the error and it points to the method
also it say's java: ';' expected it points to the end of z and end of method,, I didn't think one went there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move the code outside the main method:

```
// return a int
public class Testing 
{
  // member field
  private int sum = 0;

  // member method to change field
  public int method(int z)
  {
    return this.sum = z;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
     // You should do something here...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! :D I see I was misunderstanding the void main string bit. In Blue jay unless you run a driver you don't need it I was told with this to use it else the program wouldn't work but tbh still not sure what it means. :D thanks again!

Comment: No problem.

BlueJ has it's own main method, so you don't need to run the code. However, to execute a java program you need it.
If you compile the program above you do 'javac Testing.java', then you run it: 'java Testing'.
Right now, it will do nothing though since the main method is empty. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to create another method and declare the member variable inside the main method, you should be creating it inside the class but outside the method.

Comment: Im just not understanding this... im 99% sure the code would work in bluej. what im trying to do is just set a field to 0 run one method that mutates it to whatever the user wants then return the number :S. I know it would probably be a pain but could you show me an example so I can see what I did wrong?

Comment: I can guarantee you that the code you posted is invalid in any version of Java.

Comment: Most likely as I did/do not understand this line "public static void main(String[] args)" blueJ kinda does it for you I suppose as I only needed it when running a driver. - that line and what I had works :) in blueJ. Thanks for the help though man :D I was getting pretty frustrated with it lol.

Comment: The main method is the one that is first called when the program starts.